# Canonicalize current Git commit, using it as a reference point for forked repos

Tags: git

I am deploying several websites with Git using a common code base. Is it possible to run `git fetch` on a server and then a certain command to represent `HEAD` in relative terms from `master`?

For example, I want to know if the server is running `master/HEAD`, `master/HEAD^2`, or `master/branch^4`. Of course there could be ambiguity... maybe `master/HEAD^6` equals `master/branch^2`... here I want `master/HEAD^6`, but there is no preference for other ambiguities.

Also, I want to know if the server is "clean" (no uncommitted files and no commits on top of e.g. `master/branch^4`) or "dirty".

Bonus points if I can easily query this by accessing files in `$GIT_DIR` rather than using the `git` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the [`git describe` command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html). This command is most useful if you use tags, and gives you a short human readable description of how much the current branch has changed since the most recent tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
git log HEAD..origin/master --oneline | wc
```

`git log --oneline` will give you details about each commit between `[start]..[end]` and wc will give you a count